# Magento 2 Equivalent for Mage::getModel('catalog/product')

Tags: magento2, migration

I'm using following code:-

Mage::getModel('catalog/product')

Same code I want to use for Magento2, how can I achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 uses *Dependency Injection*. There's a couple of different ways to load a product via Magento 2, but the best practice is to use a *[Service Contract](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-contracts.html)*, which in this case is `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface`. Because Magento 2 uses dependency injection there is a preference setup for the aforementioned interface which lets Magento know which `Class` that implements the interface should be invoked (`\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository`).

Note you can also use Product Model Factory Class (`\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory`) and the Product Resource Model (`\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product`) to load a product, but it's not best practice.

To achieve something similar to Magento 1 functionality you'd do something like this for a `Block` class.

```
<?php 

namespace Vendor\Namespace\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product as ProductResource;

class MyBlock extends Template
{
    protected $_productRepository;
    protected $_productFactory;
    protected $_productResource;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        ProductFactory $productFactory, 
        ProductResouce $productResource
        array $data = [])
    {
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->_productResource = $productResource;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    // BEST PRACTICE
    public function getProductUsingServiceContract($sku)
    {
        return $this->_productRepository->get($sku);
    }

    public function getProductUsingFactoryAndResouceModel($sku)
    {
        $product = $this->_productFactory->create();
        $this->_productResource->load($product, $product->getIdBySku($sku));
        return $product;
    }

}
```